# Jquery autogrow with another textarea

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an JS textarea autogrow and textarea more than 1. In example the textarea have an ID 1,2,3,4....

Here it's the JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ctextarea").autoGrow();
  });
</script>
```

Here it's the textarea :

```
<textarea name="comment" class="comment" maxlength="200"  id="ctextarea<?php echo $msg_id;?>"></textarea>
```

And now how can I set that, if I go to textarea 2,3,4... the textarea will autogrow ?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give all the textarea, same class... and call a class selector in jquery

HTML

```
<textarea name="comment" class="comment" maxlength="200"  id="ctextarea<?php echo $msg_id;?>"></textarea>
<textarea name="comment" class="comment" maxlength="200"  ></textarea>
<textarea name="comment" class="comment" maxlength="200"  ></textarea>
```

JQUERY

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".comment").autoGrow();
 });
```

OR

you can use a name selector ...

```
$('textarea[name="comment"]').autoGrow();  // this is jus an example coz i think u 'll not have all three textarea with the same name....
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that only those textareas use the `"comment"` class then you can use the class instead of the id as a selector:

```
$(".comment").autoGrow();
```

Or use an attribute selector that uses the common name:

```
$('textarea[name="comment"]').autoGrow();
```

Or use the [attribute starts-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) with the id:

```
$('textarea[id^="ctextarea"]').autoGrow();
```

The class selector is the best option for selecting like elements - if necessary add another class to just those elements.

Comment: Thanks for answering... Appreciate with your attention... :)